# How do I send the value of an array variable in Autohotkey?

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

I'm writing an AutoHotkey script which needs to display the value of an array variable, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
MyArray := ["one", "two", "three"]

send MyArray[1]     ; "MyArray[1]"
send MyArray%1%     ; "MyArray"
send %MyArray1%     ; <empty>
send % MyArray%1%   ; <empty>
;send %MyArray%1%   ; 'Error: Variable name missing its ending percent sign'
;send %MyArray%1%%  ; 'Error: Empty variable reference (%%)'
;send %MyArray[1]%  ; 'Error: Variable name contains an illegal character'
```

I've found [posts on the AHK forums](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/18591-send-array-variables-value/)  claiming I can use `send %MyArray1%` or `send % MyArray %1%`, but both commands just reference empty variables.

**How do I send an array's value in an AutoHotkey script?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use a single `%` to force expression mode for a single parameter.**

```
MyArray := ["one", "two", "three"]  ; initialize array
Send, % MyArray[1]                  ; send "one"
```

This can be combined with regular text using quotation marks `""`

```
Send, % "The first value in my array is " MyArray[1]
```

Expression mode can be used with any command, including [MsgBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm) and [TrayTip](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/TrayTip.htm).

```
MsgBox, % MyArray[1]
Traytip, , % "The first value is " MyArray[1]
```

---

*See also*:

- [AutoHotkey - Variables and Expressions](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm)
- [When are single percent % signs used in the script?](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/149907-when-single-percent-signs-are-used-in-the-script/)

Comment: How can you ask this and answer it at the exact same time?

Comment: @Davesexcel I used the "*Answer your own question*" checkbox when submitting the question.

Comment: I was commenting on how both were done at the exact same time Aug 11/17 @ 14:15

Comment: @Davesexcel The checkbox appears when asking a question. It lets you post a question and answer at the same time.